# HTML: How to place object relative to the screen size?

Tags: html

How to place object in percentage of the entire screen in HTML, not just placing next to the previous object? For example, `<div>` at the location of 50% screen's width, 30% screen's height.

There's some requirements for this:

- Objects should be able to be placed to the desired location by percentage of the entire screen, no matter of other objects.
- Objects should be able to overwrap other objects at the same location.

Sorry for poor English :|

Comment: you need to share what you have done, some code, html, css etc. then we can further do something

Comment: I just started to make a layout of HTML, placing some objects. So there's just few <div>s.

Comment: I think you have to see this tutorial article. [Position property tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question. Let me try to answer it. In the css we have variable call vh for viewport height and vw for viewport width.

The idea is to place the element 30% of height = 30vh, and 50% width = 50vw. We can set the parent element to have relative, and the child that you want to set position with absolute position.

It would be something like below. Thanks

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

#screen .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 50vw;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  Parent
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS

```
.fixed-div{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50vw;
    top: 30vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Moves the center of the element to its original top left corner*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Then, changing z-index would let objects overwrap, right?

Comment: Correct. Just increase the value to move it higher in the stack order.